# use php to populate form fields

Tags: javascript, php, html

Ok, I'm at my wits end here. I'm making a website for a friend, to showcase his work. Each piece has it's own page. On those pages, we have a link

```
<a class="btn" href="../contact_2.html">Contact us about this item</a>
```

that takes us to the contact form page, where the user is expected to fill income details before getting in touch. What we want to do is have the 'subject' field filled with the name of the subject of the page the link was clicked form. i.e. you're on (../port_pages/38mmspruce.html), you click the "contact us about" link, and when you get to the page "contact.html", the subject field already has "38mmSpruce" populated.
As it stands, the form functions perfectly - the $_POST method is in use, and it sends the form as it should. However, trying to get the subject field to populate is driving me round the bend. The closest I got was with this html:

```
<label for="subject">Subject *</label>
<input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Please enter the subject you'd like to discuss *"
value="<? php echo $_POST='subject'?>"
rows="1" required="required">
```

which fills the subject field with:

```
<? php echo $_POST='subject' ?>
```

rather than the ACTUAL subject. I've tried this also where I've changed every occurrence of $_POST to $_GET, but it returns the same result. If I change the anchor to:

```
<a class="btn" href="../contact.php">Contact us about this item</a>
```

It fires an email off without loading the form page. I've tried adding query strings to the anchor too, but they don't return any data. I know this must be really simple but I've been banging my head against it for nearly a week now, and despite trying to research every possible variation on this question, I can't find the right answer. Here is the code for the relevant pages:

contact.php

```
<?php


$from = 'Demo contact form <example@example.com>';
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <example@example.com>';
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email', 'subject' => 
'Subject', 'message' => 'Message'); 
$okMessage = 'Contact form succesfully submitted. Thank you, I will get
back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please 
try again later';

try
{
$emailText = "You have new message from contact
form\n=============================\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
    }
}

mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&  
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $encoded;
}
else {
echo $responseArray['message'];
}


?>
```

conatact.js

```
$(function () {

$("#contact-form").submit(function () {

    var url = "contact.php";


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $(this).serialize(), 
        success: function (data)
        {
            var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
            var messageText = data.message;

            var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' 
 alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-
 dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + 
 '</div>';
            if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                $('#contact-form')[0].reset();

            }
        }
    });
    return false; 
});

});
```

And finally, the form part of the html (edit. full page posted as requested)

```
<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-
    toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Those That 
               Know</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-
         collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                 <li> 
                    <a href="mainportfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                </li>

                <li class="active">
                    <a href="contact_2.html">Contact</a>
                </li>


                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div> 
  </nav>  



  <!-- Page Content -->
 <div class="container">

    <!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
            <h1 class="page-header">Contact
                <small>Get in touch</small>
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">Contact</li>
            </ol>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->



    <!-- Content Row -->

        <!-- Map Column -->

        <!-- Contact Details Column -->

            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/About Main Pic.png"
   alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Contact Details</h2>
            <h2>Those That Know HQ<br>Wallsend-on-Tyne<br>
            </h2>
            <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> 
                <abbr title="Email">E</abbr>: <a
   href="mailto:name@example.com">example@example.com</a>
            </p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 
                <abbr title="Hours">H</abbr>: Open 24 hours</p>

            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline list-social-icons">
                <li>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" 
  href="#"><i class="fa fa-
  facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-envelope"><i
 class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="btn btn-social-icon-large btn-instagram" 
 href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
                </li>
                <button onclick="goBack()">Back</button>

        </div>
    </div>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <h1>Get in touch with  <a href="contact_2.html">Those
 That Know</a></h1>

                <p class="lead">If you'd like to contact me about 
placing an order, or about anything you've seen on the site, please 
fill in the form below.</p>
                <p>Please include information about the piece you've 
been looking at. It'll help us to get started on your order.</p>    


                <form id="contact-form" method="post" 
action="contact.php" name="contact-form" role="form">

                    <div class="messages"></div>

                    <div class="controls">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="form_name">Name *</label>
                                <input id="form_name" type="text"
 name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name 

 *" required="required">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                <input id="form_email" type="email" 
name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email 
*" required="required">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="form_subject">Subject * 
</label>
                                <input id="form_subject" type="text" 
name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter the
 subject you'd like to discuss *" 
                                value="<? php echo $_POST['subject'];?
>"
                                rows="1" required="required">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="form_message">Message *
</label>
                                <textarea id="form_message" 
name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message here *"
 rows="4" required="required"></textarea>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-
success btn-send" value="Send message">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="text-muted"><strong>*
</strong> These fields are required.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </form>

            </div><!-- /.8 -->

        </div> <!-- /.row-->

    <!-- /.container-->

      <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Copyright &copy; Those That Know 2016</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script>

function goBack() {
window.history.back();

}



</script>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"> 
 </script>
    <script 
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/
bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
    <script src="js/contact.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it's a Bootstrap form, and the .js and .php files came with it. I've changed the mail settings to real ones for testing to make sure it works, which it does, but I simply cannot figure out how to make the php 'echo' the subject from a page into the relevant field in the form. I've also removed all of my attempts at adding query strings after the page name in the link because I couldn't make any of them work. I really need a straight up answer to this puzzler-this is the 3rd time I've asked on here, and nothing is working. I think it's obvious that I have very weak skills, but I'm working on them and fixing this problem would really help me to move on to a new set of problems.
Your help is gratefully appreciated in advance.

Comment: `echo $_POST='subject'` <- typo?

Comment: one mistake at first spot: `<?php echo $_POST='subject' ?>` has to be `<?php echo $_POST['subject'] ?>`. Otherwise you're overwriting `$_POST` and `true` will be echoed.

Comment: `<?php echo $_POST['subject'] ?>`  is guaranteed to create a XSS vulnerability.   Use output filtering to fix this. Ref: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your contact_2.html to contact_2.php so it gets parsed by the PHP interpreter.

Change the href in

```
<a class="btn" href="../contact_2.html">Contact us about this item</a>
```

accordingly.

Finally replace your `<? php echo $_POST='subject' ? >` to

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['subject'])) echo $_POST['subject']; ?>
```

like @manniL said.

Comment: Hi farmio, I've tried that. when I change the reference in the anchor to contact_2.php, when I click the link it goes to a new page with the success message and I get an email. The form at contact_2.html doesn't get loaded. Thanks anyway. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Looking at your comments you may be just missing a semicolon beforehand. Is there more php code in the contact_2.php? Can you post the content of that contact_2.php?

Comment: Hi @farmio, I've changed the name of contact_.php back to contact_2.hmtl as the .php extension was just throwing up a blank page. I do already have a contact.php posted above, but I'll add the full contact_2.html page to the original post if that helps? Thanks for getting involved and helping me!

Comment: Renaming the file to .php normally signals the webserver to send it to the php-interpreter before sending it to the user requesting is. The php-interpreter reads your statements (encapsulated in <?php ?> and computes them. If your webserver sends the file as is then you have "<?php echo $_POST['subject'];?>" in your subject field because its treated as text.

Comment: Remove the whitespace after the first questionmark in  `<? php echo $_POST['subject'];?>` it should be `<?php ...`

Comment: Yo @farmio, I've removed the whitespace, same result. When I tried earlier to change contact_2.html to contact_2.php, all I got was a blank page instead of my contact page. Th address bar DID contain the info I wanted though i.e. "contact_.php?subject=farah", so I think that part of it was working. Thanks again!

Comment: i just tested it and saw that there is another whitespace at your closing bracet: `$_POST['subject'];? >` . It was hard to see because of a line break ;). Php statements should read `<?php ... ?>` i edited my answer with the full statement. Do you get error logs running the script?

Comment: Hey @farmio, you're a real star for sticking with me here. I've done as you advised above and it's mainly all working - I changed contact_2.html to contact_2.php, and I removed the whitespace. Now when I click the link, it loads contact_2.php as it should - apart from the subject field being empty. In my error logs, it points to line 176 - the line where "value=<?php..." is. The full message in console for this error is : `[29-May-2016 14:53:24 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ttk2/contact_2.php on line 176`. Thanks again!!

Comment: try copying it from here: https://3v4l.org/2BDsb

Comment: No dice, buddy. Getting the page with the form, subject field still empty.

Comment: You said earlier that the address bar did change to contact_2.php?subject=farah . In that case you're sending a GET request and you would need to use $_GET['subject']

Comment: Yo @farmio YOU FIXED IT FOR ME!!! I CANNOT EXPRESS MY GRATITUDE ENOUGH!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I'm new on here so how can I boost your rep here? I really can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo $_POST='subject'`, use the correct syntax here:

```
echo $_POST['subject'];
```